# Force Method to throw an exception in Mockito

Tags: hibernate, jpa, exception, mocking, mockito

I'm having such a method :

```
@PostMapping("/methodToBeMocked")
public GenericMessage methodToBeMocked(@QueryParam(value = "msg") Long msg) {
    try {

        JmsMessageConstruct.buildId();

        b.saveToDbUsingHibernate(new Object());
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        GenericMessage genericMessage = new GenericMessage();

        genericMessage.setStatus("KO");

        return genericMessage;

    }

    GenericMessage genericMessage = new GenericMessage();

    genericMessage.setStatus("OK");

    return null;

}


public class B {
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public void saveToDbUsingHibernate(Object obj) {
    entityManager.persist(obj);

}
```

}

The issue is that i can not mock the b method so when i call the method saveToDbUsingHibernate it will throw an exception.
Actually the method saveToDbUsingHibernate  will not throw an explicit exception because it's calling Hibernate JPA EntityManager to save it.

Comment: But the method is not throwing exception at all?

Comment: This method saveToDbUsingHibernate is not throwing exception .That's why i'm posting this question :